# Web camera can't see any face in face_tracking project

Tags: opencv, processing

I am making project `face_detection` using `OpenCV`, `Arduino` and `Processing`. However I have faced some problems.

The code is correctly written but after compiling, the web camera of my laptop can't see any face, only dark window.

```
'import hypermedia.video.*;
 import java.awt.Rectangle;
 import processing.video.*;
 OpenCV opencv;


 int contrast_value    = 0;
 int brightness_value  = 0;



 void setup() {

 size( 1000, 500 );

 opencv = new OpenCV( this );
 opencv.capture( width, height );                   // open video stream
 opencv.cascade( OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE_ALT );  // load detection 
 description, here-> front face detection : "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"


// print usage
   println( "Drag mouse on X-axis inside this sketch window to change contrast" );
  println( "Drag mouse on Y-axis inside this sketch window to change brightness" );

}


public void stop() {
opencv.stop();
super.stop();
 }



 void draw() {

// grab a new frame
// and convert to gray
opencv.read();
opencv.convert( GRAY );
opencv.contrast( contrast_value );
opencv.brightness( brightness_value );

// proceed detection
Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect( 1.2, 2, OpenCV.HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, 40, 40 );

// display the image
image( opencv.image(), 0, 0 );

// draw face area(s)
noFill();
stroke(255,0,0);
for( int i=0; i<faces.length; i++ ) {
    rect( faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height ); 
}
}




 void mouseDragged() {
contrast_value   = (int) map( mouseX, 0, width, -128, 128 );
brightness_value = (int) map( mouseY, 0, width, -128, 128 );
}
```

Output is black window. Why is this happening? [Here's my output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIRV5.jpg)

Comment: Can you please properly format your code? It's very hard to read without proper indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `OpenCV` with `Processing` but I think you're missing something on the `opencv.capture` part, since I see you're not specifying anything about the source of the video stream.

[Here](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/blob/master/examples/LiveCamTest/LiveCamTest.pde)'s the code for a live camera test... It passes `this`, and then the other stuff.

The extract of the code I think may solve your problem is this:

```
void setup() {
    size(640, 480);
    video = new Capture(this, 640/2, 480/2);
    opencv = new OpenCV(this, 640/2, 480/2);
    opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);  

    video.start();
}
```

I think this might help!

Source: [OpenCV for Processing on GitHub](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing)

Comment: Can you please include the pertinent code changes in your answer instead of linking to other sites?

Comment: Sure. By the way a link to a code to GitHub doesn't seem too bad for me